# How to automatically scroll to the certain widget in a screen when pressing a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is it possible if I want to move my screen to the bottom when pressing a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find this link to get yourself up and running.

It is always a good idea to try something yourself and upload the code here so we can help better :)

[Scroll to Position Flutter](https://cogitas.net/scroll-position-flutter-listview/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article, it really help me :)